# What is Differential Inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, constructor, prototype

I was trying to understand Prototypal inheritance in JS when I came across this [article](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/3-different-kinds-of-prototypal-inheritance-es6-edition-32d777fa16c9) by Eric Elliott.

After reading the article, I learned a couple of things and I wanted to check whether my understandings are correct or not.

Differential inheritance (one of the three types in prototypal inheritance) is used when we link objects using prototypes, ie. If a property is not found on the object, the lookup is delegated to the delegate prototype to which it was linked to. This inheritance uses references for lookups. The following are different ways:

1. Constructor functions:

```
function Cat(param) {
  this.name = param;
}
Cat.prototype.meow = function meow() {};

function SuperCat(param){
  Cat.call(this, param);
}
SuperCat.prototype = Object.create(Cat.prototype);
SuperCat.prototype.constructor = SuperCat;
const superCat = new SuperCat('kitty');
```

2. Classes (syntactic sugar over constructor functions):

```
class Cat{
  constructor(param){
    this.name = param;
  }
  meow(){}
}

class SuperCat extends Cat{
  constructor(param){
    super(param);
  }
}
const superCat = new SuperCat('kitty');
```

3. Factory functions:

```
const proto = {
  meow(){
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}
const Cat = (name) => Object.assign(Object.create(proto), {name});
const SuperCat = (name) => Object.create(Cat(name));

const superCat = SuperCat("kitty")
```

Any correction or acknowledgment would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is the first time i have heard the term _"Differential inheritance"_ in javascript. At the end of the day, you are just creating a prototype chain and that is what's known as prototypal inheritance.

Comment: Yes. The more we know JS, the more we understand we don't know JS. ;)

Comment: You are referring to _"Differential inheritance"_ as one of the three types of prototypal inheritance. As far as i know, that's the only prototypal inheritance in javascript. What are the other two types?

Comment: Concatenative Inheritance and Functional Inheritance. Please read the article for reference.  Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_inheritance